# Ranking of produced "brain fatigue" from different mind intensive activities

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience

I'd like to know if there has been an study, or different studies for each activity with which the ranking could be done, that determines a ranking like that with mind intensive activities, I refer to things like playing chess, performing advanced maths, programming, writing a book with care of all its details, performing IQ tests and whatever activity that would produce "brain fatigue" in a typical person within some hours.

I guess the more brain activity it supposes the more tiring the activity would be, although not sure about that. It would also be a good point to determine how hard some activities are.

Comment: What do you mean by "brain fatigue"--decrements in performance? the subjective feeling of fatigue? psychophys or physiological changes?

Comment: Decrements in performance would be the most appropiate term.

Comment: I believe the technical term is Directed Attention Fatigue. I've never seen a study ranking individual tasks but if we break down the variables involved we could probably make a good guess. The biggest variables are the amount of time spent on the task and the level of distractions present when completing the task. If you are given pure silence with a 5 hour math exam you would adhere more directed attention fatigue then  say completing that math exam in a loud noisy environment or listening to music, you brain will be able to wander in between computations.

Comment: I'd also assume it would vary depending on your personality and/or skills.